# How to cut image overflow div using react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, overflow

[Want to get Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz5lL.png)

I capture Image using react-webcam.
And captured Image overflow `<div>`. So, I want to get image only inside `<div>`.

If, I use `hidden` It just hide, not drop(or crop).

So, I want to know how to delete outside image.

**Capture Image**

```
<CustomWebCam    
          onLoadedData={() => {
            setTimeout(() => setError(false), 500);

            setLoading(false);
          }}
          audio={false}
          ref={webcamRef}
          screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
          screenshotQuality="1.0"
          forceScreenshotSourceSize
          videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
          onUserMediaError={() => {
            alert('Error');
          }}
          muted
        />
```

**I want to use only inside `div` image in here**

```
          <ReactImageCrop
            width={windowDimensions.width * 0.7}
            height={windowDimensions.height * 0.7 * 0.5}
            imageData={imgSrc}
          />
```

Comment: I don't know how to upload image in-page, so I upload image with link sorry :'(

Comment: Please include code.

Comment: @YTG Okay, include code

Comment: @Dev_Kim did you manage to solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @TCL Maybe yes..? I used getBoundingClientRect.
`const imageTarget = document.getElementById('full');`
`const imageRect = imageTarget.getBoundingClientRect();`
This code get full size Image position.

`const target = document.getElementById('guide');`
`const clientRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();`
This code get guide line image position.
And use ctx.drawImage function

Comment: Put an exclamation mark (!) before the link brackets: `![link][1]` to make the image be in-page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.img {
  width:460px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

<div class="img">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NrcV.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use only inside image other component. If i use `overflw: hidden`, It isn't cropped image :'(

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to determine to know the width and height then add a class depending on:
with > height "class landscape"
height < width "class portrait"

```css
.Landscape {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Portrait {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```